# Applying boundary conditions to PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Can anyone help me on how to define the following BC for a PDE in Maple or Mathematica:

\begin{equation}
Diff(f(t,r,\theta),r) \ \ \ when \ \ \ r=a \ \ \ equals \ \ \ V \cdot a^2 \cdot sin\theta\\
Diff(f(t,r,\theta),\theta) \ \ \ when \ \ \ r=a \ \ \ equals \ \ \ V \cdot a \cdot sin^2\theta
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mathematica,

```
Derivative[0,1,0][f][t,a,\[Theta]]==V a^2 Sin[\[Theta]]
Derivative[0,0,1][f][t,a,\[Theta]]==V a Sin[\[Theta]]^2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: In Maple:

\begin{equation}
D[2](f)(t,a,\theta) = V \cdot a^{2} \cdot sin\theta \\
D[3](f)(t,a,\theta) = V \cdot a \cdot sin^{2}\theta
\end{equation}